# OpenGLES Add User Interactions

Tags: iphone, xcode, opengl-es

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-opengl-es-for-the-iphone

From the above link they created tutorial by No Nib File.
But i need to add User interactions like , adding Progress View.

Please help me. i am new to iphone OpenGLES.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The presence or absence of a Nib file within the application does not affect its ability to handle touches, either in buttons or through direct touch handling.  For example, my iPhone/iPad application [Molecules](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/molecules) (for which the source code is available under the BSD license) has both buttons for changing state and gestures for interacting with an OpenGL ES model, yet it doesn't use Interface Builder for any part of its interface.

You can get the same interface capabilities whether you implement them in Interface Builder or in code.